# Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I try to get the data from Firestore on Firestore but it returns this object does not have the foreach method. I also tried to console in the console statements below: The `console.log("this")` does not work, but the other console.log works.
Here is the code:

```
let fstore = firebase.firestore();
fStore
  .collection('user-info')
  .doc(userID)
  .get()
  .then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
      if (doc.id != userID) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        user_list2.push(doc.data());
        console.log('this');
      }
    });
  });

fStore
  .collection('User')
  .get()
  .then(function (querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
      if (doc.id != userID) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        user_list.push(doc.data());
        console.log(user_list);
        console.log(user_list.length);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure you're actually getting data back from the API?

Answer (score 1):

`fStore.collection("user-info").doc(userID).get()` does not yield a QuerySnapshot.  It yields a DocumentSnapshot, because it can only ever return a single document - the one you identified in `doc()`.  DocumentSnapshot does not have a forEach method, because there is nothing to iterate.

You should instead just call data() on the object you get:

```
fStore
  .collection('user-info')
  .doc(userID)
  .get()
  .then(function (snapshot) {
    const data = snapshot.data();
  })
```

Your second query **can** return multiple documents, since it's asking for every document in a collection, so you get a QuerySnapshot intead.

The bottom line here is that `get()` on a DocumentReference can only ever return a single document, and that `get()` on a CollecitonReference or Query can return multiple documents.  They are different types of queries with different results.

Answer (score 0):

```
let query = firestore.collection('col').where('foo', '==', 'bar');

query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
  let docs = querySnapshot.docs;
  for (let doc of docs) {
    console.log(`Document found at path: ${doc.ref.path}`);
  }
});
```

Looks here: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html

You can check if docs is not empty

```
   if (querySnapshot.docs.length === 0) {
     return;
  } else {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    });
  }
```